# hybris - Rest service 404 page not found

Tags: rest, http-status-code-404, sap-commerce-cloud

I installed a new instance of hybris server in a VM and made it available on a public internet page. I am trying to call the Product resource REST server or even a simple list of countries REST service.

http://xxx.xxx.com/ws410/rest/countries

However, I am getting an error with the status "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found". Please can you help me?

Am I missing something? Should I Configure ws410 path somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Did you added `platformwebservices` extension into your localextensions.xml file ? Please ensure that you have below line in your localextensions.xml file

```
<extension name="platformwebservices" />
```

For more details check [this](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/tr52/Trail+~+Webservices).

`ws410` is a default webroot path which is defined in platformwebservices/extensioninfo.xml file.

```
<webmodule jspcompile="false" webroot="/ws410"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you add the port 9001 par default on your URL. Try this http://xxx.xxx.com:9001/ws410/rest/countries